# Distribution of permissions in react application

Tags: reactjs

I have a react app, an object with permissions comes from the backend and depending on the user's role or selected permissions, the user has access to one or another functionality in different components(buttons, certain table cells, etc.)

What is the best way to implement this functionality on the front-end side? I thought that you can use a certain service that will accept all permissions and, using the API context. For example, already scatter them throughout the application, depending on the component. Is this the normal way and how can you do it better?

I have a little silly sketch of how I see it, I would like to know how to do it better.
https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-joliot-nkur7?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Context is not a bad choice. You can also pass them down directly from upper components. The choice between these two is never easy.

Comment: You example is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Scattering any logic through out an application sounds like a poor design choice for any feature. Instead you should have centralized code that does this. For example, this could be a function that you can call as needed such as `hasPermission()`.

Comment: While that's true, you have to somehow distribute data that can be passed to that function. And React context is one way to do that. This is not about scattering *logic* (which usually consists only from checking that an array contains some value) but about the way how to reach the permissions from every part of the app.